# Where Application.UserName is picking user name from

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have an excel application where I want to personalise data as per user that is using it. In VBA, I am using Application.UserName to filter data based on that. Problem is that a person has changed her last name and excel application is still picking her previous name.
Does anyone know where excel stores username information when I use Application.Username, so I can change that if possible.

I have already tried reinstalling excel. Relogging in excel but it didn't work and it still picks up previous name instead of new name.

Comment: Options -> General -> Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office -> User name. From there you get the `Application.UserName` (this is read/write property btw)

Comment: Thanks alot braX that really helped. This really is the place where I need to replace her name. Also is there a way I can restrict anyone else to update with password protection so not on the entire file but on this option. Otherwise people might change name to fetch other people's data.

Comment: You could try using Environ("Username") instead as this is associated with the OS environment variable and not the application.